# How to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.0 on apache?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I cannot enable tls 1.0 and 1.1 on my server. 
I have this configuration:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCompression off
SSLHonorCipherOrder on

SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4
```

What I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I have `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.21` openssl version

Comment: you forgot to add the most important thing, which openssl version are you using? and also make sure apache reports the same in it server error.log when it starts. Also generally people define `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3` instead, or even `SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2`, not sure of the gain of convoluting it the way you defined it.

Comment: I think those cipher suites are either all TLS 1.2 spec key exchanges or non-applicable.

Comment: For readers coming here after 2020: Are you sure you want this? SSL/TLS protocols prior to TLS 1.2 are deprecated and considered insecure now.

Answer (score 3):

The following config does the trick for me (Ubuntu 20 with Apache2 v2.4.41 and openssl 1.1.1f):

```
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          CDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:@SECLEVEL=1
```

Notice the @SECLEVEL=1 at the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you. @SECLEVEL=1 ended our 3+ hour debugging session!

Comment: Note that this is for serving TLS1.0/1.1. So If your Apache 2.4.41 need to serve TLSv1. If you need to connect to TLSv1 it will have no effect. So if you have something like `ProxyPass / https://my.old.server.local:443/` then you need to enable TLS1 in `openssl.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many variables and not enough information to give you an answer that will solve your problem. You are better off using the [Mozilla SSL Config generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/), then [testing with SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to make sure you are getting at least an A-.

Comment: I'm usign SSL labs to perform my check and I see this: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=tropicalseo.net. I've followed all the rules but tls 1.1 is still not enabled. I'm not sure what informations I should give you. Thanks

Comment: You don't want TLS 1.1 enabled: https://community.qualys.com/thread/16565-is-there-a-reason-for-still-having-tlsv11-enabled

Comment: As for TLS 1.0, it depends on your audience. Only older clients use it. Re-generate your config using the Mozilla tool and report back.

Answer (score -1):

SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2

It should work

Comment: This is the same config that is listed in the question.